# how to fill white space at center when orientation changes in android

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-fragments, orientation

I developed an application that has a fragment in parent center and is very well displayed. When I change the orientation of my cell phone every thing resizes very well, but that fragment is again parent centered.(overlaping a few items from top and bottom of screen) where I need it to cover the AVAILABLE white space at center of screen.  Below is the xml of fragment. Any suggestions?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="layout.message"
    android:background="#f5f5dc"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/phone"

        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="Mobile Number"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/amount"

        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="Amount to Pay"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Confirm To Send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/send"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"

        android:background="@drawable/shape"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This isn't really an Android Studio question.

Comment: and marking it negative is not really a bold job . have tolerance sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use fragment, why not use two xml files? One with horizontal attribute, the other with vertical attribute. See the code below and create another xml file and just change android:orientation to vertical.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

//Your code here

</RelativeLayout>
```